# Excel's COUNTIF() function returns a wrong count

Tags: excel

Spent an hour on this but can't figure out what seems to be the problem. Any help is appreciated.

[image: What's wrong with IFCOUNT]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put in the `=`

```
=COUNTIF(A13:A15,"=<abc")
```

The mathematical sequence is `>=` or `<=` not `=>` and `=<`, so countif will see the beginning `<` or `>` as Greater than or Less than, but if it is preceded by the `=` it assumes it is part of the text and not the mathematical operand.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works Scott but how the hell "=" solves the problem? I can't find this from the Excel's documentation.

Comment: @tatskie see edit for explanation, Please remember to mark as correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer.